# TYPO3: typoscript does not respect line breaks in txt file

Tags: typo3, typoscript, robots.txt

I generate a robots.txt file and all works fine with realurl ...
only that there is no way that linebreaks are respected, why ?

typoscript:

```
# robots.txt
robots = PAGE
robots {
    typeNum = 201
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:text/plain
    }
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypoScript property additionalHeaders is of type "numeric array" with subproperties according to https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#additionalheaders

That's why the content of the HTTP response is treated as *text/html* instead of *text/plain* as requested.

This TypoScript code should do the trick:

```
robots = PAGE
robots {
    typeNum = 201
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        debug = 0
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-type: text/plain
    }
    10 = TEXT
    10.value (
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
)
}
```

The main difference is (right)

```
robots.config.additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-type: text/plain
```

instead of (wrong)

```
robots.config.additionalHeaders = Content-type: text/plain
```

Additionally, the option

```
robots.config.debug = 0
```

is set so no "parsetime" information is ever rendered to the robots file.

Comment: thx benni, it sounds fine but there must still be something disturbing, I get a oneliner anyhow ... any other setting that might be off ? Typo3 v7.6.18

Comment: I tried it on a fresh installation and it's correct, I use EXT:T3SBootstrap that causes my specific problem I guess, with that extension disabled it works fine ...

Answer (score 1):

Using the code Benni provided I get this:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```

so it seems like the answer is correct.
You can try to add the linebreak manually with this code:

```
robots = PAGE
robots {
    typeNum = 201
    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        debug = 0
        additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-type: text/plain
    }
    10 = COA
    10 {
        1=TEXT
        1.value = User-Agent: *
        2=TEXT
        2.char = 10
        3=TEXT
        3.value = Disallow: /
    }
}
```

In my case the result is the same, but maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: believe it or not, also your snippet still gives one line, I never doubted the code of Benni, there must be some setting in my specific case that disturbes ... I would not know where to look, what comes prior to this snippet ?